# Make spritenode scale to be larger while executing action?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I have a sprite named `savior`, which is set to this size initially: `savior.setScale(0.2)`

When the user touches the screen, this is executed:

```
savior.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(stopSaviorAnimate))

savior.runAction(SKAction.sequence([diagonalRight,
    SKAction.runBlock({
        let Touchdelay = 0.75 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let Touchtime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Touchdelay))
        //during delay
        dispatch_after(Touchtime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            //after delay
            self.savior.runAction(backToPlace)
            self.savior.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(startUpSavior))
        }
    })
]))
```

As `diagonalRight` is executed (not after or before, at the same time), I need the sprite to "grow" or progressively scale to reach a scale of `0.3` during the delay.

I have tried writing `savior.setScale(0.3)` at the during delay, but the sprite does not grow - it just immediately snaps to being scaled to 0.3 after `diagonalRight` occurs, which is not what I need.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a scaling animation, you can use the `scaleTo` `SKAction`.

```
let scale : CGFloat = 0.3
let duration : NSTimeInterval = 1.0
let scaleAction = SKAction.scaleTo(scale, duration: duration)
node.runAction(scaleAction)
```

Comment: How do I make the scale action occur while diagonalRight occurs?